# Why can't I position the elements correctly on the circumference of a circle?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wQXCL/427/

Works great. Positions the image at the end of the arc. But this is because I took away 90 degrees (`Math.PI/2`) when positioning the image.

Before taking away 90 degrees : http://jsfiddle.net/wQXCL/428/

To me it looks like the formula to work out points on a circle :

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

The start angle is 90 degrees, is this correct ?

Or am I interpreting the whole thing incorrectly ?

Comment: starts directly east of the central point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3's [`arc.startAngle()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#arc_startAngle) is specified as:

> Angles are specified in radians; **0 corresponds to 12 o’clock (negative y)** and proceeds clockwise, repeating at 2π.

In contrast, [trigonometric functions on the unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle) are defined as follows:

> the ray from the origin (0, 0) to (x, y) makes an **angle θ from the positive x-axis**, (where counterclockwise turning is positive)

To compensate for this, you need to subtract *π / 2* from the arc's angles to use them in trigonometric calculations.

Comment: But that will still mean increasing the angle moves the point counter clockwise. An alternative is to use a (y,x) coordinate system, so that for example the point at angle a, sistance r is y = r*cos(a), x=r*sin(a).

Comment: @dmuir That is not correct. When using screen orientation the y-axis is pointing downwards, which implies that angles from the positive x-axis will increase when turning **clockwise**. For this reason an increase in the angle's value will move the point clockwise. Have a look at the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t9xLf1r/) which increases the angle by 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.0 * `Math.PI`;. The point's positions is thereby rotated clockwise.